# MVVM How do I: Embed Views refering to their VMs?

Tags: design-patterns, xaml, mvvm

I have one main View that represents the main window, in that I have areas and controls.

I want each of these areas to be underlined by anoter VM.

How do I declare the XAML, and how do I refer the DataContext of each nested view according to the parent View's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main page can have multiple navigation frames that represent the areas.  Each page navigated to in a frame can have it's own view model.  Setting the data context for the child pages is no different than setting the data context for the main page.  To change a page in a frame you call frame.navigate passing the uri of the page you want to load.

Comment: But how do I pass params to the nested View's VM?

Comment: You can pass parameters to the views through querystrings.  So you might call Frame.Naviagate(new Uri(string.Format("/Views/Orders.xaml?id={0}", orderId), UriKind.Relative));

Comment: No, I am not talking when navigating, I am asking when I nest a view in a view, how do I attach the nested view's VM and related it to it's parent view data?

Comment: I worked up an example of this, not sure how to display it all here.

Comment: Can you post it on your blog? maybe just upload it to codeproject/codeplex or google code etc.?